# Disturbing peace by playing table soccer

Tags: germany

There is a soccer table, which stands in an apartment and the neighbour feels disturbed by it every time a game is played. He has already

- called the police several times, but they usually came after 8 p.m. or never caught the residents playing football (so it was always quiet for them),
- called the landlord, who then asked the residents to stop "playing basketball" in the apartment (there was clearly a misunderstanding),
- and in addition also a criminal charge was filed (for disturbing the peace), but it was dropped due to lack of public interest. (I think, he therefore has no other option but to file a private lawsuit.)

I can hardly find anything serious on the net about table soccer and disturbing the peace. It's mostly about musical instruments. I can imagine, however, that it goes in the same direction.

The soccer table itself is of course not very quiet, but I would say that a violin, a trumpet, a piano, a drum set, etc. are much louder. Personally, I would also rate a guitar with steel strings a bit louder if you practice a courageous piece. But of course the instruments also make a different kind of noise. It is also worth mentioning that the neighbour feels disturbed with every little thing and generally shows little tolerance.

The neighbour actually always comes to the door after 2 to 10 minutes after every start of the game and rings and knocks, even if he is ignored every time. There are still several other issues between him and the landlord and him and the table soccer players. A peaceful communication is no longer given. Therefore some misunderstandings are not cleared up at all. So I'm interested only in the general legal situation which leads me to

**the question:**

When and how long do you have to endure your neighbours' table football game and under which circumstances are the game enthusiasts not allowed to enjoy their hobby? (They don't play from 8 p.m. and also not on Sundays. But maybe they are even allowed to play until 10 p.m.?)

---

<sup>Please feel free to edit the question text. It is not easy to formulate correct technical terms if you are not an expert in this field and also not a native speaker. When editing, simply fill in the "Edit Summary" with meaningful words. Then I can understand that.</sup>

Comment: I think you're on the right track with the 8pm curfew. Consider to check the leasing documentation for activities beyond a specified time. Every lease I've signed for housing has exact times in the document. Once you have that information, post it on the door of the "basketball" game in large type.

Comment: Agree that this can simply be checked. But `how long do you have to endure your neighbours' table football game` is still an open question (and imho the more important one). Or from another perspective: `how long in a day is it allowed to play table soccer in a multi-family house`?

Answer (score 1):

There are no national law regulations, but most of the local laws have the same timeframe.

Sunday and holiday's : all day

Other: 22:00 to 06:00 (some areas until 07:00)

Some areas : 13:00 to 15:00 (not in Berlin)

Overy loud things over long periods should be avoided.

No right for gigantic Saturday night parties until the early hours of the morning, but a notice of warning of the horrors that are to be expected is appreciated (but not every week).